# How to add a resize arrow to a JPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans

I Need to add a resize arrow to be controlled with the mouse, just like the arror that apears in the edge of the window, but I need it to be used in a jPanel, in JAVA. [SOMETHING LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEG7C.png)

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a MouseAdapter and on mouseMove check whether to setCursor of the appropriately oriented cursor. While mouseDrag resize and validate the panel. There should be sample code in the net.

Similar resizable would be a JSplitPane.